# Inner class in python without affecting the normal operation of the program

Tags: python

I'm learning Python at the same time I'm working on a subject project, and I realized that I have two classes (class senA and senB) that represent two similar elements, therefore, I wondered if those two classes could be grouped in a general class (General class), I was looking at the inner class but unfortunately as I must access the arguments of each class (senA and senB) always generates an error. My code is like this

```
class senA():
    def __init__(self, arg, arg2):
        self.arg = arg 
        self.arg2 = arg2 

class sensB():
    def __init__(self, arg3):
        self.arg3 = arg3


for i in range (3):
    obj = senA('hx', 'ex')
    objx = sensB ('hello')
    values=list(attrs.values())
    valuesx=list(attrsx.values())
    list_VALORES.append(values)
    list_metodos.append(valuesx)

print(list_metodos)
print(list_VALORES)
```

and it works well but I would like to associate the classes senA and senB into one called classGeneral

```
class general():
    class senA():
        def __init__(self, arg, arg2):
            self.arg = arg 
            self.arg2 = arg2 
    
    class sensB():
        def __init__(self, arg3):
            self.arg3 = arg3
```

but it generates constant errors or for example the program stops recognizing the classes when I instantiate the objects. Any idea how I could solve this

Sorry about my bad English, but I'm not a native English speaker. I try to be as clear as possible

Comment: I tried your example then i changed obj = senA('hx', 'ex') / objx = sensB ('hello') to obj = general().senA('hx', 'ex') / objx = general().sensB('hello'). This works perfectly for me.

Comment: You'll have to access these classes as `general.senA` and `general.senB`, but why? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Joki, you're absolutely right. That's how it works best. It really helped me a lot, it's clear that I have to keep learning about the classes and how to access them. Again, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, what you want is to create a separate module to hold the `senA` and `sensB` classes. If you create a python file called `general.py` that holds the class definitions, you can then import that into another python script. So in your `main.py`, you would add the following line to the top: `from general import senA, sensB`, and you would be able to use them like normal.

If your classes are all similar and share attributes, than you could also use inheritance. For example:

```py
class General:
    def __init__(self, arg1):
        self.arg1 = arg1  # argument that both senA and sensB use

class senA(General):
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        super().__init__(arg1)
        self.arg2 = arg2

class sensB(General):
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, arg3):
        super().__init__(arg1)
        self.arg2 = arg2
        self.arg3 = arg3
```

You could then access attributes from those classes as normal, for example:

```py
a = senA('arg1 value', 'arg2 value')
print(a.arg1)  # returns 'arg1 value'
print(a.arg2)  # returns 'arg2 value'
```

Comment: I hadn't thought about the module, it's kind of what I want to do. While I'm looking over the super() class to see what I can understand. Thank you very much for your answer.